# Fixed/loose distance between nodes with networkx

Tags: python-3.x, networkx, topology

I want to represent a computer network. Devices have several ports that connect to another device's port. For example, here you see that port `1/1/1` of device `a` connects to port `1/1/1` of device `b`. So far, so good ...

[image]

Now I want to stick together (real close) ports to nodes, so that the distance between a node and its port, be zero. But the distance between ports-to-ports, should be loose. Bear in mind that `ports` and `nodes` in my network are represented both as `nodes` in the networkx abstraction ...

So far I have achieved this by controlling the weight of edge, when linking together a node and its port, by assigning a high value.

```
G.add_edge(node,node_port[0], w=2000)
```

I can read that value later on with `pos = nx.spring_layout(G, weight='w')`. But no matter how big `w` is, I cannot achive a zero distance between nodes and ports.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Your second paragraph is confusing, could you clarify? I'm not familiar with the format 1/1/1 for ports

Comment: It's just a label for the name of the port. It's common in networking that ports be identifed as `a/b/c`. So what I'm saying is that, for example, node `b` has 3 ports: `1/1/1`, `1/1/2` and `1/1/3`.

Comment: `spring_layout` does have options to include an edge weight in its calculations. 
 Here's the documentation: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.layout.spring_layout.html

Answer (score 1):

When you run:

```
pos = nx.spring_layout(G, weight='w')
```

you get a dictionary in which keys are nodes and values are 2D coordinates. You can use this to create a new dictionary in which you manually overwrite the port positions with that of their device, if I understand you correctly.

Specifically:

1. initialize a new dictionary `pos2`.
2. loop over the nodes: if the node is a device, look up its coordinates in `pos` and add it to `pos2`. If the node is a port, look up its corresponding device's coordinates in `pos` and add the port node to `pos2` with those coordinates.

Then call `nx.draw`, passing `pos2` as the position of your nodes. Hope that is clear and that I'm interpreting you correctly.